# Kernel debugging

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, debugging

I would like to study the flow of some linux device drivers and some minimal flow of kernel (threading cum context switching and interrupt management).

How can I debug the linux kernel? What are the basic steps for doing that?

Recently i successfully compiled and integrated new kernel (2.6.34.7) into my machine running the 2.6.29 kernel.

Comment: Linus is adamantly opposed to debuggers, so the support for that is rather scanty. Try to decipher the data flow you are interested in by reading the code, hanging out in http://lwn.net or http://www.kernelnewbies.org, reading books, ... [The problem is that much is time-critical, can't stop to take a peek, printk might mess up execution, ...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you really need. Probably simple `printk()` function is gonna be OK for the beginning. There is also the `/proc` interface you can use to get useful information from kernel.

If you need something more complicated, use KGDB (kernel debugger).

Comment: Yes. I need the information about the usage of KGDB itself.

Comment: Renjith, http://kgdb.linsyssoft.com/using.htm

Comment: there is kernel-probes, and then `stap`, DTrace for Solaris/BSD/Mac? kernels. Pretty innovatively useful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your kernel sources folder and have a look inside `Documentation/` folder. Start with going through the file `kernel-parameters.txt` looking for references to debugging.

If your kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL` option set, you can easily adjust the verbosity of kernel messages via the `loglevel` boot option.

Answer (score 0):

The other options other then KGDB would be debugging the kernel using the QEMU and GDB. Unlike the KGDB, the QEMU-GDB combine requires only a single machine.